# Need open source search engine api, for fastest file(plain text,pdf,office documents, audio, etc) search

Tags: search, full-text-search, search-engine

I need open source search engine api for searching the files on my server. The files includes text file,pdf file audio file, in short maximum formats supported. I had one option for lucene 3.5.0 which searches the plain text and according to servey its one of best. Any suggesations would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucene is your friend. Have a look at http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is helpful, but still the audio one is needed..... Thanks.....

Comment: What do you mean by audio file? Speech recognition (sphinx or some clouding service) or just to parse lyric embedded (id3 tag libs http://www.id3.org/Implementations)?

Answer (score 1):

Check [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) as well.